# specify a region when creating an Amazon AWS SQS queue in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

How can I specify a region when creating an Amazon AWS SQS queue in Ruby? the [docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/frames.html) don't have anything to say on the subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the top of the [SQS documentation for the Ruby SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/SQS.html), it says you can set configuration "directly on the SQS interface". This means you can do something like this:

```
sqs = AWS::SQS.new(:region => 'us-east-1')
queue = sqs.queues.create("myqueue")
```

Alternatively, you can specify it globally using `AWS.Config`, like this:

```
AWS.config(
  :access_key_id => 'YOUR_ACCESS_KEY_ID',
  :secret_access_key => 'YOUR_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY',
  :region => 'us-east-1')
```

The documentation for configuration is here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/Core/Configuration.html